# swift tutorial newbie issue

Tags: ios, swift

I'm following this very basic tutorial of swift in apple's official website.
You can see it in this link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson1.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH3-SW1

I think there is an issue with one of the scripts.

I ran this piece of code in playground

```
class NamedShape {
var numberOfSides = 0
var name: String

init(name: String) {
    self.name = name
}

func simpleDescription() -> String {
    return "A shape with \(numberOfSides) sides."
    }
}

let namedShape2 = NamedShape(name: "my named shape")
namedShape2.numberOfSides = 7;
namedShape2.simpleDescription()
```

in

```
let namedShape2 = NamedShape(name: "my named shape")
```

The output is NamedShape and not "my named shape". I don't think that what was meant to be.
How can I fix that?

thanks

Comment: `let namedShape2 = NamedShape(name: "my named shape")` means you initialize a variable named `namedShape2` and it's an object of class  `NamedShape ` with a name property set to "my named shape"

namedShape2.name is "my named shape" that's what you want

Comment: If you `print(namedShape2.name)`, you will see "my named shape".

Answer (score 0):

Make your class conform to CustomStringConvertible protocol and add a computed String var called description:

```
class NamedShape: CustomStringConvertible {
...    
    var description: String {
        return "A shape with \(numberOfSides) sides."
    }
}
```